# Will jQuery work on a very large document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, report

Hey there programming peps! I have a question re: jQuery. We have a software application that is producing a very large HTML report... large on the order of 500-2000 printed pages. It can take Google Chrome between 12-20 seconds to load it from the hard drive.

There is a some JavaScript in use which serves only to give the HTML version of the report some additional functionality. Right now, all of the events are fired off from inline HTML `onclick`s and so on.

If I convert to jQuery and use selectors to bind the events, the selectors could easily be matching 10's of thousands of elements. Plus, the typical way to use jQuery (eg., `$(document).ready()`) would cause the click event not to fire until the document was fully loaded.

**So the questions are:** 
Is jQuery up to this task? Or am I better suited leaving inline script?
If it is, are there certain techniques I need to use to make it work well? 
And is there a way to circumvent the "no events until document load" scenario?

**And a secondary question** *(this one just occurred to me as I was writing this)*:
This report is being sold to a client. What are my license obligations if jQuery is included as apart of the report?

***Edit***

@jfriend00 : I've been at a bit of a loss on how to do this (split the report up). The report is issued in 2 formats: HTML and PDF. The clients want to have a digital manual available from which they can print sections. They also want the HTML version because it provides anchors which link key parts. The JavaScript allows for a popup that provides a view into the underlying data that the report was based on. What has happened is that we've run into a scaling problem. The data being analyzed has increased greatly and so has the size of the resulting report.

For confidentially reasons, the report cannot be live online nor on an internal intranet. It has to be a deliverable that will run on an individuals local machine.

If anyone has tips on how to handle this gracefully, I would love to hear your ideas. This is an issue that has been plaguing me for some time.

Comment: Do yourself and your viewers a huge favor.  Your web page needs a new design.  You need to add more dynamic behavior so that data is loaded upon demand rather than 2000 pages of data all loaded at once.  jQuery will work fine with this as long as you have enough memory in the computer and patience - it's just a matter of how long you want to wait for certain operations to complete.

Comment: 500-2000 pages is overkill... split it somehow

Comment: @jfriend00 : I updated the question with some additional info related to your comment.

Comment: Since nobody ever wants to actually read 2000 pages of a report, the way you typically solve this problem is you allow the viewer to navigate to the desired data they are interested in and then you load and display just that data using ajax or using fresh page loads.  If they then want to see different data, you then dynamically load different data and display it to them.  This requires a more thoughtful design and rethinking how the viewer wants to tell you what they want to see and then being able to fetch and display just that information.  But, the scalability and performance is greater.

Comment: @jfriend00 : The only way I can think to accomplish that is to send them a zipped directory of HTML files. To keep the pages quick, I would probably have to split the report into 100-200 separate documents.

Comment: I don't know the subject matter so can't help on how to split it up, but if you can't envision any reasonable way to make a multi-page navigation of the results, then you either don't understand what the viewer might want or you aren't really rethinking the problem.  Nobody needs 2000 pages on screen at once.

Comment: @jfriend00 : I appreciate your advice. Our client feedback has only been positive regarding the reports. But I think this is because our report is the only way they can get to the information they need, so they are putting up with it. But that is my opinion as the developer, not the clients. As you suggested, I can't imagine that they are finding the report easy to deal with. But it can be difficult to justify the time and expense to change something when the clients haven't expressed any dissatisfaction.

Comment: Or, you can be ahead of the curve and show leadership with your clients and propose that their data has gotten large enough that the user experience is starting to suffer because of both difficulty of finding what they want and because of load time performance and they should consider a new project that comes up with a design that works better with the larger amount of data for both now and the future.  I get that the client pays the bills and they decide where to spend the $, but sometimes you have to educate them about what issues need some attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery's up to pretty much any task. Question is if the browser these reports will be loaded into can keep up.You could embed a "start processing" directive every certain number of lines in the report, so that after (say) 100 lines of report are out, there's a JS call to start your script on those 100 lines.

Then another 100 lines of report, and another function call. Painful, but at least those first few hundred lines would be interactive as the rest of the page loads.

As for #2, that's a legal issue. jquery's under dual MIT/GPL licensing, so you're probably ok, but talk to a lawyer to be sure. "But some random weirdo on the internet said it was ok!" is not a valid defence if/when you get hauled into court on a copyright violation rap.

Answer (score 4):

As far as `document.ready` is concerned you can use the `.live()` function to bind your events so the event handlers will be added as elements are added to the DOM:

Instead of:

```
$(function () {
    $(<selector>).bind(<event>, <callback>);
});
```

You can use `.live()`:

```
$(<selector>).live(<event>, <callback>);
```

Description of `.live()` (http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.

Comment: I will try this if I end up switching to jQuery. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As for the license part I think your fine since jQuery is free to use and does not have specific rules for client deployment.

As for the performance part I think jQuery is not the problem. Of course, everything will slow down a bit with a large DOM. I think you also need to look at browsers since they all use different js engines to execute your scripts.

If the script gets to slow anyway, you might want to split things up or add more specific selectors and than handle your report bit by bit.

Answer (score 1):

Paginate your 500-2000 printed pages document and use ajax to load the content dynamically.